# How to get RedGate Sql Prompt to work in SSDT project?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, sql-data-tools, red-gate-sql-prompt

I am working on a `SSDT` project and I would like to use `intellisense` and `snippet` support of `RedGate Sql Prompt`, but I am unable to get that working. All I get from `SqlPrompt` is the name of the database and my snippets, nothing about the tables.

What I've tried so far without getting it to work:

- disabled VS's built in intellisense for sql
- added connection in sql server object explorer and server explorer

I am using VS2017 and SQL RedGate 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it doesn't support table/column/parameter expansion.

Comment: Hello Ed. I read that somewhere too, but I am pretty sure I somehow had this working at one point, but just can't figure what I had done at that time. By the way, I appreciate your blog, big time! It has been very helpful to get me started with SSDT.

Comment: Ya that does, but I miss the snippet feature of sqlprompt, thats the only reason I want that over built in.